Why does Jeff think that having a story at all seems gross?
In the counselor’s office in Spider-Man Across The Spider-Verse (2023), Weber reveals to Miles’s parents, Rio and Jeff, that
Miles received a poor grade in Spanish. Miles claims it was due to missed classes
and his busy schedule:

Weber: All right. We can still salvage this.
Jeff: I'm sorry, "salvage"?
Weber: Miles has a great story to tell.
Jeff: Having a story at all seems gross.

Why does Jeff think that having a story at all seems gross?

This is a good question and I can see why this would be confusing to someone whose first language isn't English.

Jeff is not happy that the counsellor is suggesting that they 'play the race card' in order to get around Miles' obvious shortcomings (truancy and a relatively poor grade in Spanish), in order to get him into one of the best colleges in the country.
As far as Jeff is concerned, they should be looking at Miles' hardworking attitude, strong grades and excellent attendance as indicators that he'll do well and achieve a good degree, not some invented "story" about his roots and heritage that explains why he isn't as good a student, but still deserves preferential treatment. Worse, there's the unspoken suggestion that Miles hasn't had every possible advantage that his family can give him in order to advance his academic career.
Simply put, nobody's ever given Jeff a boost because of his background and he clearly doesn't respect others who rely on a sob-story to get ahead in life. He thinks that's gross and isn't afraid to call it like he sees it.
